# How do I loop through a Set in the html

Tags: angular, angular8

I'm trying to use *ngFor on a Set containing other Sets.

```
<div class="card-deck" *ngFor="let cardDeck of recentlyAdded; let i=index">
                    <div class="card" *ngFor="let documentary of cardDeck">
                        <img [src]="getSantizeUrl(documentary.poster)" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
                        <div class="card-body">
                        <h5 class="card-title">{{ documentary.title }}</h5>
                        <p class="card-text">This is a longer card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
                        <p class="card-text"><small class="text-muted">Last updated 3 mins ago</small></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

...

pastebin other code https://pastebin.com/AP1Vwa7P

There are no console errors, only this in the html source code:

```
<!--bindings={
  "ng-reflect-ng-for-of": "[object Set]"
}-->
```

Comment: What is the data you are trying to show.... are we supposed to guess what `result` contains, that you are working with= ;)

Answer (score 2):

To iterate over `Set` first you have to convert it into an `Array` then loop through it.

```
let arrayOfSet= Array.from(pass your set)
```

Comment: Not really! Set is an iterable object. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ruu5h5

Comment: @JonnyD Please check your code properly you are creating an array out of `  `recipientsArray = []` which is initially empty. That is why you get an empty array. My point here is you do not need `Array.from` to loop through `ngFor`. Because `ngFor` works on any iterables. `Set` is an iterable.
`